# How can I add captions inside a bootstrap carousel-item, while preserving the responsiveness and alignment of the indicators and controls?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

```html
<div id="myCarousel" className="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="true">
      <div className="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" className="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
      </div>
    
      <div className="carousel-inner">
        <div className="carousel-item active">
          <SomeImage />
          <div className="ifx__caption">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. lorem20</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="carousel-item">
          <SomeImage /> 
          <div className="ifx__caption">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="carousel-item">
          <SomeImage /> 
          <div className="ifx__caption">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button className="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span className="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button className="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span className="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
```

I have this standard `Carousel` container with a caption element `ifx__caption` inside each `carousel-item`. The purpose for this is because I want the captions to be outside the image, beneath the `indicator` buttons, but to slide with the image. The issue here however is that the `indicators` are absolutely positioned at `bottom: 0`, and adding the captions element expands the `carousel-item` height which distorts the positioning of the `indicators`. Same thing happens with the `controls` too. They are positioned at 50%, which is supposed to be in the middle, but when the captions expand the height, 50% is no longer the middle.

How can I make sure both the `indicators` and `controls` are positioned correctly where they're supposed to be by default?

If I change the positioning of the `indicators` from `bottom: 0` to let's say 30%, that would be visually well aligned, but it's not going to be dynamic, meaning, if the captions's length is increased by adding more text, the 30% positioning gets distorted again. Same goes for the `controls` too.

What other way can you think of adding a caption beneath the `indicators` that isn't part of the `carousel-item`, but slides with it? Or to be inside the `carousel-item`, but to make sure the `controls` and `indicators` are properly aligned in a way that would dynamically adjust for a responsive design?

Answer (score 0):

try this code from Bootstrap version 5.1.3 It is a carousel with captions.

You can also check the documentation of Bootstrap carousel here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/

Make sure to also include the stylesheet and scripts needed in order for it to work properly. You can check it here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/

**Carousel with captions. Code from Bootstrap:**

```html
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>First slide Title</h5>
        <p>First slide paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Second slide Title</h5>
        <p>Second slide paragraph.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Third slide title</h5>
        <p>third slide paragraph.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```